# How to modify values in a column of a DolphinDB table

Tags: dolphindb

I need to modify some values in a column of a DolphinDB table. But I got some error messages when executing my code.

For example, I'd like to set the 6th value to -1 in a column named `id`. This is my code:

```
t = table(1..10 as id)
t[`id][5] = -1
```

After executing the preceding code, I got:

> Syntax Error: [line #2] Please use '==' rather than '=' as equal
>   operator in non-sql expression.

I wonder what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

To modify some elements of a DolphinDB column of an in-memory table, please use the following three ways:

1. update sql

   update t set id = -1 where rowNo(id) = 5
2. column name plus index

   t[`id, 5] = -1
3. column name plus condition

   t[`id, rowNo(id)==5] = -1